# cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile в Hello, World!

Tags: c++, windows, стек, g++, cygwin

Cygwin компилирует "Hello, world!", но при запуске программы выдаёт **0 [main] hw 1025 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to hw.exe.stackdump**.
Я пытался найти решение проблемы, но во всех случаях ошибка была в самом коде задавшего вопрос, и я не понимаю как я смог переполнить стек не используя ни одной переменной.
я компилирую программу коммандой  `g++ -o hw hw.cpp`

*код helloworld'a*

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

*налииче cygwin в PATH*

[image: cygwin прописан в PATH, в системных переменных]

*содержание файла hw.exe.stackdump*
[image: содержание файла который создаётся после запуска программы в cygwin]

*предустановленные мной пакеты для cygwin*
[image: предустановленные пакеты]

*ошибка в терминале cygwin*
[image: ошибка в терминале cygwin]

```
$ g++ -o hw hw.cpp
$ ./hw.exe 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: А дебаггер что говорит? Может антивирус выключить?

Comment: Ну и, точно ли вам нужен Cygwin? Просто MinGW не пойдет?

Comment: дебаггер ложится при попытке запуска этой программы.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл причину такого поведения.
В гайде, по которому я устанавливал `Cygwin`, было рекомендовано установить последную версию пакетов. Покопавшись ещё на форумах, я заметил совет:

> Просто переустанови пакет или используй более старую версию.

Я попробовал, и всё получилось. Причина была в том, что большая часть пакетов последней версии была тестовой (и видимо нестабильной).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]